# Error : installing ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

i would like to install ng-bootstrap in my angular project , it's giving me this error:

```
    PS C:\xampp\htdocs\SNCF\Angular-SNCF> ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
ℹ Using package manager: npm
⚠ Unable to find compatible package. Using 'latest' tag.
⚠ Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.

The package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree       
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-sncf@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"12.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-13T15_17_41_606Z-debug-0.log
✖ Packages installation failed, see above.
```

i tried also this : `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` ---> it's giving me the same error

and this : `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps` ---> it's giving me the same error

and this : `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force` ---> it's giving me the same error

i tried to update angular : `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

But still not working

Answer (score 0):

try deleting your node_modules folder and your npm cache and try again

Comment: i tried this : npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps and it's working now , i still have just one prob i tried to install popperjs with : npm install @popperjs/core --legacy-peer-deps   , but it's giving me an error :  ERROR in ./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/index.js 4:0-102

export 'detectOverflow' (reexported as 'detectOverflow') was not found in './createPopper.js' (possible exports: createPopper, popperGenerator)

Answer (score 0):

### the Message say to you use angular version @14.0.5
it's not compatible with ng-bootstrap version

solution is:
use
@angular/cli@13.0.0
@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2

compatibility table: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

now, to sol this problem i used :
npm i -g @angular/cli@14.1.0
and
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.1.1